# angularjs ng-repeat duplicate items

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using http request with angular js ng-repeat to repopulate a list.

it goes like this:

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in itemlist">
    content goes here...
</div>
```

than, in the controller, I call a function with interval, that sets item variable to be the new list:

$app.communicate is a function that makes http request to the server

```
    initializeItemList = function() {
        $app.communicate('item','loadItemList',{user_id : localStorage.userId},function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.recent_item = data.recent_item;
            $scope.itemlist= data.itemlist;
            }
        },function() {});       
    };

    initializeItemList();

    $interval(initializeItemList, 4000);
```

in practice, every interval run duplicates the itemlist.

I tried to add filter unique, but it won't help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use track by

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in itemlist track by $index">
    content goes here...
</div>
```